# Joining two collections efficiently?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, underscore.js, async.js

I have run into an issue where I am trying to join two arrays similar to the ones below:

```
var participants = [
                      {id: 1, name: "abe"}, 
                      {id:2, name:"joe"}
                   ];
var results = [
                  [ 
                      {question: 6, participantId: 1, answer:"test1"},
                      {question: 6, participantId: 2, answer:"test2"}
                  ],
                  [
                      {question: 7, participantId: 1, answer:"test1"},
                      {question: 7, participantId: 2, answer:"test2"}
                  ]
              ];
```

Using nested loops:

```
_.each(participants, function(participant) {
  var row, rowIndex;
  row = [];
  var rowIndex = 2
  return _.each(results, function(result) {
    return _.each(result, function(subResult) {
      var data;
      data = _.find(subResult, function(part) {
        return part.participantId === participant.id;
      });
      row[rowIndex] = data.answer;
      return rowIndex++;
    });
  });
});
```

This works ok as long as the arrays are small, but once they get larger I am getting huge performance problems.  Is there a faster way to combine two arrays in this way?

This is a slimmed down version of my real dataset/code.  Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

**FYI**

My end goal is to create a collection of rows for each participant containing their answers.  Something like:

```
[
    ["abe","test1","test1"],
    ["joe","test2","test2"]
]
```

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and added it.

Comment: Tag away, it is very much underscore

Comment: @AbeMiessler would it be safe to say that the participants collection is a much smaller array of data? Or is it the other way round?

Comment: What's the output meant to look like? All those _.eachs are confusing me.

Comment: Heh, yeah it's kind of brain scrambling.  I am basically attempting to create a row for each participant that contains all of their answers.  Added my desired output.

Comment: Do you have a working jsFiddle and a jsperf that answers can be compared against?

Comment: I don't.  The actual data set I am working with is giant, so it would be difficult to paste into something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perf* is not from the for loops so you can change them to _ iteration if they gross you out

```
var o = Object.create(null);

for( var i = 0, len = participants.length; i < len; ++i ) {
    o[participants[i].id] = [participants[i].name];
}

for( var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; ++i ) {
    var innerResult = results[i];
    for( var j = 0, len2 = innerResult.length; j < len2; ++j) {
        o[innerResult[j].participantId].push(innerResult[j].answer);
    }

}

//The rows are in o but you can get an array of course if you want:

var result = [];

for( var key in o ) {
    result.push(o[key]);
}
```

*Well if _ uses native .forEach then that's easily order of magnitude slower than for loop but still your problem is 4 nested loops right now so you might not even need the additional 10x after fixing that.

Comment: To dump the properties of o into result array, wouldn't you want to use the hasOwnProperty guard here? or create o with Object.create(null);

Comment: @Kastor If you are certain that you are in an umolested environment, with an unmolested `Object` then it's absolutely fine. If your are unsure of that then, yes, wrap it. `hasOwnProperty` is a relatively expensive call and it will have a noticible effect on the performance of this routine with a large data set, especially on older browsers, but not so much on modern browsers. [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/with-and-without-hasownproperty). Using `Object.create` will limit this routine for use on modern browsers only, so maybe not a good solution.

Comment: @Xotic750 The question is for node.js though. Raw CPU performance is never an issue in browser CRUD UIs, that's the reason people can use angular and ember and not notice anything.

Comment: @Esailija Thanks. Unfotunately I am unable to do any testing in Node.js and my knowledge there is limited. These were the most helpful comments that I could provide. :)

Comment: Awesome thank you!!!  So is the performance gain from a combination of removing a level of nested loops and finding elements in a hash table VS however underscore is doing it?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Yes, `_.find` is like `Array#indexOf`, it searches the entire array every time. In hash table the record can be found much faster. And another issue is indeed nesting so many loops, just try to imagine in your head how many operations it is if you nest 1000 items 4 times: `1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000` = `1000000000000` where as unnested loop 4 times 1000 is `4000`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using ECMA5 methods

Javascript

```
var makeRows1 = (function () {
    "use strict";

    function reduceParticipants(previous, participant) {
        previous[participant.id] = [participant.name];

        return previous;
    }

    function reduceResult(previous, subResult) {
        previous[subResult.participantId].push(subResult.answer);

        return previous;
    }

    function filterParticipants(participant) {
        return participant;
    }

    return function (participants, results) {
        var row = participants.reduce(reduceParticipants, []);

        results.forEach(function (result) {
            result.reduce(reduceResult, row);
        });

        return row.filter(filterParticipants);
    };
}());
```

This will not be as fast as using raw `for` loops, like @Esailija answer, but it's not as slow as you may think. It's certainly faster than using `Underscore`, like your example or the answer given by @Maroshii

Anyway, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMBAe/) of all three answers that demonstrates that they all give the same result. It uses quite a large data set, I don't know it compares to the size you are using. The data is generated with the following:

Javascript

```
function makeName() {
    var text = "",
        possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy",
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    return text;
}

var count,
    count2,
    index,
    index2,
    participants = [],
    results = [];

for (index = 0, count = 1000; index < count; index += 4) {
    participants.push({
        id: index,
        name: makeName()
    });
}

for (index = 0, count = 1000; index < count; index += 1) {
    results[index] = [];
    for (index2 = 0, count2 = participants.length; index2 < count2; index2 += 1) {
        results[index].push({
            question: index,
            participantId: participants[index2].id,
            answer: "test" + index
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, we have a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/make-rows-comparison) that compares these three methods, run on the generated data set.

Comment: I updated your jsperf example to show that the original function doesn't work, and to reflect Esailija's update.

Comment: Looks like your answer is faster on IE 10 and Esailija's is faster on Firefox 24.

Comment: I like the Firefox, but only hardcore nerds figure out how to "do the internet" without clicking the blue E.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it with large amounts of data but here's an approach:

```
var groups = _.groupBy(_.flatten(results),'participantId');
var result =_.reduce(groups,function(memo,group) {
  var user = _.find(participants,function(p) { return p.id === group[0].participantId; });
  var arr = _.pluck(group,'answer');
  arr.unshift(user.name);
  memo.push(arr);
  return memo ;
},[]);
```

The amounts of groups would be the amount of arrays that you'll have so then iterating over that with not grow exponentially as if you call `_.each(_.each(_.each` which can be quite expensive.

Again, should be tested.

Comment: The original function didn't work, so any function is infinitely faster. Still, check out the jsperf test Xotic750 made: http://jsperf.com/make-rows-comparison/3

Comment: Good stuff... The accepted answer is clearly the best solution